# Convert from quote item to order item is not working

Tags: magento2, fieldsets

There is custom field in `quote_item` table same as `sales_order_item` both column name and type are same.

I want to convert `quote_item` table to `sales_order_item` table. so I have used `fieldset.xml` to convert those data,

my fieldset.xml file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
<scope id="global">
    <fieldset id="quote_convert_item">
        <field name="customcolumn1">
            <aspect name="to_order_item" />
        </field>
        <field name="customcolumn2">
            <aspect name="to_order_item" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</scope>
</config>
```

but its not working so strange

Comment: Please clear all cache & rebuild all indexing. after try again. :)

Comment: Have you investigated log files, any error messages?

Comment: yes i checked log files no error message

Comment: That configuration should be enough try to clean all `var/generation` and `var/di` and cache. and as @David Verholen said, debug your data there.

Comment: I think you have to create plugins for the quoteItem:getExtentionAttributes and quoteItem:set ExtentionAttribute, the same for the orderItem, so that getDataFromFieldset to work.

Answer (score 21):

In Magento 2 without using fieldset you can also copy custom data from quote item to order item by using plugin.

create `di.xml` in your module etc folder.

**app/code/Vender/Yourmodule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="cedapi_quote_to_order_item" type="Vender\Yourmodule\Model\Plugin\Quote\QuoteToOrderItem"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a class to your module and define a function. **app/code/Vender/Yourmodule/Model/Plugin/Quote**
Create `QuoteToOrderItem.php` file

```
<?php
namespace Vender\Yourmodule\Model\Plugin\Quote;

use Closure;

class QuoteToOrderItem
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item
     * @param array $additional
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
  public function aroundConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem $item,
        $additional = []
    ) {
        /** @var $orderItem \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item */
        $orderItem = $proceed($item, $additional);//result of function 'convert' in class 'Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem' 
        $orderItem->setCustomDesign($item->getCustomDesign());//set your required
        return $orderItem;// return an object '$orderItem' which will replace result of function 'convert' in class 'Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem'
    }

}
```

Comment: +1, This is working fine for quote to sales_order_item. Could you please show how to convert sales_order_item to sales_invoice_item?

Comment: I tried with some more data. It is not working.

Comment: Thanks, It's working fine. But in multiple address checkout it's not working. do we've to follow any other pattern to update the quote item value in order item table during the multiple address checkout ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the converting is done here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/ToOrderItem.php#L61

you may want to debug here and see what happens

**UPDATE**

had the same problem today. It seems to be a bug since the [converting](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/ToOrderItem.php#L61) itself seems to work, but the [populeateWithArray](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.0/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Item/ToOrderItem.php#L78) then strips the new attribute.

I solved it with an around plugin on the ToOrderItem class like described [here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager_plugin_system)

Answer (score 1):

On your fieldset, try this:

```
<fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_item">
```

instead of what you currently have:

```
<fieldset id="convert_quote_item">
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem::convert()**
After

```
    $orderItemData = $this->objectCopyService->getDataFromFieldset(
        'quote_convert_item',
        'to_order_item',
        $item
    );
```

The **$orderItemData** contains the data of the custom field that you declare in **fieldset.xml**

But after that Magento create order item by **Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterfaceFactory** and set data of **$orderItemData** to it

```
    $orderItem = $this->orderItemFactory->create();
    $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
        $orderItem,
        array_merge($orderItemData, $data),
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface::class
    );
```

They will ignore custom fields that didn't define in **OrderItemInterface**

Answer (score 0):

Try to create observer of `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` and there get the object of order using `$order=$observer->getOrder();` and set your values on that order object. 
it will solve your problem.

==== **Update**======

create `events.xml` and put the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="event_name" instance="Companyname\Packagename\Observer\Observername" />
    </event>
</config>
```

now create observer file `Observername.php` add this code

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {  
        $quote=$observer->getQuote();
        $order=$observer->getOrder();
        $order->setCustomcolumn1($quote->getCustomcolumn1());
        $order->setCustomcolumn2($quote->getCustomcolumn2());
    }
```

Comment: Here we are talking about quoteItem to orderItem not quote to order

Comment: I have added comment field after payment methods and before apply discount. I have added the custom column to quote and sales_order. I am using this event observer code to get comment data but not getting comment field data. please help me.

Comment: In quote I am not getting data of custom field which i have added in Review & payment step after Payment Method