# Can't copy data from quote_item to sales_order_item

Tags: quoteitem, sales-order-item

I have a custom value (In a Magento 2.3.3 installation )that gets added to the quote_item table when I add an item to the basket. When I go to checkout I want to pass that value to the same-named column in the sales_order_item table. I am using the event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before to copy my quote data to the sales order table but for some reason, the data to be inserted into the sales_order_item table won't store. Below is the code I am using.

```
foreach($order->getItems() as $item) {
    $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($item->getQuoteItemId());
    if ($quoteItem) {
        if($quoteItem->hasData('deposit')){
            $item->setData('deposit', $quoteItem->getDeposit());
        }
    }
}
```

If I debug straight after the contents of $item then I get the value but it is not storing in the table.

Comment: Seem you have a duplicate question.
Maybe you'd see the answer here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100463/convert-from-quote-item-to-order-item-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($order->getItems() as $item) {
 $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($item->getQuoteItemId());
 if ($quoteItem) {
 if($quoteItem->hasData('deposit')){
    $item->setData('deposit', $quoteItem->getDeposit());
 }
  $item->save();
}
```

**Try this code, It may help you!!**

Comment: I thought I could do that to but I get the error:"success":false,"response":null,"error_message":"Something went wrong while generating the Sage Pay request: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: @MartinPeasley, can you state your complete problem, I hope above code doesn't make any issue

Comment: So using the event sales_model_service_quote_submit_before I am saving a custom value that gets stored in the quote_item table. This correctly adds to the corresponding column in the sales_order table. If I also want to save data to a custom column in the sales_order_item table the value doesnt get saved. To save data to sales_order_item do you have to use extension attributes as I didn't need to  to add data to a custom column in the sales_order table?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the issue was that I needed to use extension_attributes to save a custom value to the sales_order_item table.